# Deploy Virtual Machine with Azure-Powershell concurrently

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am running a script with powershell to create virtual machines, for example I have a list of 10 virtual machines and when I run the script they are only created from 5 to 5, does anyone know what can be due?

The structuring of the script is a workflow function that is responsible for creating the NIC and everything related to the virtual machine. This function is called every time you want to create a new machine through a loop in the following simplified way:

```
workflow Provision-AzureVM{
   param( <params> )

   inlinescript{ #code create VM }

}


#code of loop calling workflow
foreach($servers in $arrayServers){

   Provision-AzureVM <params> -JobName "JobExample" -AsJob

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell workflows by default only allow 5 parallel streams running.

There's supposed to be a `-throttlelimit` parameter to change that behavior.

Also, you probably want ARM Template to that do that for you. They handle dependencies and concurrency and dont have that limit

check this thread:

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ae1efc9-46d7-426f-b26f-c43dab43adb4/change-powershell-parallel-limit?forum=Offtopic

Comment: Thank you so much, first I will try to change the workflow "throttlelimit" if it's possible, and if not going to change workflow for function.

Comment: I just have changed "workflow" to "function" and deleted "inlinescript" and it works!